# CRONTAB, When to set path variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have two bash scripts that both work when I run them.

However when I try to run them in `cron`, one script(Scipt 2) works and the other(Script 1) does not.

I have narrowed down the problem to setting the `PATH` variable for both the `find` & `date` commands used in the non working script(Script 1).

I am a little confused though as the other script(Script 2), that originally worked in `cron`, also has the `find` & `date` commands.

Why would this be?

Linux Distro: Ubuntu Server

Script 1(needs path set):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Delete Cam Folders Older Than 7 Days
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin <- MUST ADD THIS TO WORK PROPERLY IN CRON
file=$(find /cams -type d -mtime +5 | tr '\n' ' ')

if test -z "$file"
then
    echo "$(date "+%b %d %Y %T") : No directories older than 7 days"
else
    echo "$(date "+%b %d %Y %T") : Deleting Directies ${file}"
 #       find /cams -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} +
fi
```

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_date=$(date '+%A_%b-%d-%Y')
#mkdir /cams/$file_date

# record_hq.sh
# Record ip cam in segments
# Start of Day to Create Directory
# This will print the current date and time in a format appropriate for storage
STARTTIME=$(date '+%I%M%p')

## IP Camera Names ##
# Creating date stamps for each of the five cameras
CAM1D=/CAM01_$STARTTIME
#CAM2D=CAM2D_$STARTTIME
#CAM3D=CAM3D_$STARTTIME
#CAM4D=CAM4D_$STARTTIME
#CAM5D=CAM5D_$STARTTIME

## Network and Local Storage Locations  ##
HQDIR="/cams/"

## Record Time per File ##
HQLENGTH="3600" # (Runtime expressed in seconds)

## Record Settings ##
#
# -v 0    // Log level = 0
# -i      // Input url
# -vcodec // Set the video codec. This is an alias for "-codec:v".
# -an     // Disable audio recording
# -t      // Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration
#

echo "$(date "+%b %d %Y %T") : (Hourly Recording) Started recording file                 ${CAM1D}.mkv"
if ffmpeg -v 24 -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://admin:Halo1Rules!@192.168.12.2:554/h264Preview_01_main" -vcodec copy -an -t $HQLENGTH $HQDIR$file_date$CAM1D.mkv ; then
    echo "$(date "+%b %d %Y %T") : (Hourly Recording) Stoped recording file 
else
    echo "$(date "+%b %d %Y %T") : (Hourly Recording) Recording Script Failed"
```

Comment: Please indicate what flavor/distribution of Linux this is - it would be unusual for `/bin` and `/usr/bin` not to be in the default cron path, I think. Also whose crontab (user/root/system) are you using? Include the actual crontab entries if possible.

Comment: As steeldriver says, not having `/bin` and `/usr/bin` in the default `PATH` in cron is highly unusual. Is the `PATH` set in the crontab itself? What does the scheduling of these scripts look like? What are the actual errors you get from running the script via cron? (I'm also noticing that the second script appears to be cut off at the end).

Comment: I edited the question to include that I am using Ubuntu Server.  I do not have the path set in the crontab but I am certain setting it would allow both scripts to work. 
 I more asked the question to understand why one script requires the path to be set. Script 1 is set to run once a day while Script 2 runs every hour.  Script 1 does technically run however the find command does not return any results without the path line.  Once I add the path line the find command returns accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesnt use  .bashrc paths. Normal execution uses .bashrc paths. This is the reason you need PATH variable.

Also your PATH variable looks different.

Have a look the systemwide cron file looks like this

```
This has the username field, as used by /etc/crontab.
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file.
# This file also has a username field, that none of the other crontabs 
do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user   command
42 6 * * *   root    run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
47 6 * * 7   root    run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
52 6 1 * *   root    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
01 01 * * 1-5 root python /path/to/file.py
```

Comment: in crontab i call both scripts by the absolute path.  Additionally, both files have the same permissions

Comment: this was because of .bashrc

Comment: I think maybe your path was messed up

Answer (score -1):

Well both scripts now appear to be working without adding the PATH command.  Even after a restart.  Really not certain of what happened.  I can't even continue to test so I will answer my question for now.